# Sorting in O(n) intersect

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, hashset

> - Let `S1` and `S2` be two sets of integers (they are not necessarily disjoint).
> - We know
>     that `|S1| = |S2| = n` (i.e. each set has `n` integers).
> - Each set is stored in an array of length `n`, where
>     its integers are sorted in ascending order.
> - Let `k ≥ 1` be an integer.
> - Design an algorithm to find the
>     `k` smallest integers in `S1 ∩ S2` in O(n) time.

This is what I have so far:

1. Create a new array called `Intersection`
2. For each `e` in `S1` add `e` to hashset **in O(n) time**
3. For each `e` in `S2` check if `e` exists in hashset **in O(n) time**
4. If `e` exists in hashset add `e` to `Intersection`
5. Once comparisons are done sort `Intersection` by count sort **in O(n) time**
6. return the first `k` integers

Thus O(n) + O(n) + O(n) = O(n)

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Since the arrays are already sorted in ascending order, this can be done using the 2-pointer technique (almost the same as merge procedure in mergesort).

Comment: Hashing is a hammer to kill flies. Use a merge operation.

Comment: @Yves: Merging is using a slightly *smaller* hammer to kill flies - it's better, but it's still a hammer :-) There's no need to combine the lists in *any* way, it can be done in O(n) time and O(1) space. Unless of course, you meant "virtual" merge operation as per my answer, in which case I apologise in advance.

Comment: @paxdiablo: if the results must be available for further processing, a merge is mandatory and by no means overkill. By the way, it suffices to replace your print by an append and you get exactly the same algorithm.

Comment: Counting sort is most probably inappropriate, as its complexity is not O(n) but O(n+m) where m is the size of the range of the keys. Usually, m>>n.

Comment: @Yves, good point but with one possible proviso. If you have two lists each with a billion elements (millions in common), there's a big difference between "intersect-merging *fully* the two lists and picking out the first three" (what I understood you to be proposing) and "finding the first three intersects with two pointers". Maybe not in terms of complexity analysis but very likely in terms of run time :-) Unless you meant a *limited* intersect-merge where you stop after the first N common values have been found, which is basically what my answer posits. If that *is* the case, apologies.

Comment: if it has to finish in O(n) time, am i still able to use count sort? i know count sort is O(n+k) but this still belongs to O(n) right?

Comment: 101ldaniels: for a count sort, the collating phase (allocating items to a bucket) is O(n) time. I think technically processing the buckets to get the counts is O(1) time and space but with a big "1" :-) So effectively O(n). But, if you have 15 32-bit unsigned integers, allocation to a bucket will take fifteen "steps" but processing the four billion buckets will be a fixed four billion steps (one per 32-bit value). I wouldn't do it that way, especially since you already have a better way in the answers.

Comment: @paxdiablo: when the number of buckets is a parameter, the processing time is O(m), which is more informative than O(1).

Comment: @paxdiablo: indeed, full merging would be stupid, you stop as soon as you've found k elements.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're definitely on the right track but there's actually no need at all to generate a hash-table or extra set. As your two sets are *already* sorted, you can simply run an index/pointer through both of them, looking for the common elements.

For example, to find the first common element from the two sets, use the following pseudo-code:

```
start at first index of both sets
while more elements in both sets, and current values are different:
    if set1 value is less than set2 value:
        advance set1 index
    else
        advance set2 index
```

At the end of that, `set1 index` will refer to an intersect point provided that neither index has moved beyond the last element in their respective list. You can then just use that method in a loop to find the first `x` intersection values.

Here's a proof of concept in Python 3 that gives you the first three numbers that are in the two lists (multiples-of-two and multiples-of-three). The full intersection would be `{0, 6, 12, 18, 24}` but you will see that it will only extract the first three of those:

```
# Create the two lists to be used for intersection.

set1 = [i * 2 for i in range(15)] ; print(set1) # doubles
set2 = [i * 3 for i in range(15)] ; print(set2) # trebles

idx1 = 0 ; count1 = len(set1)
idx2 = 0 ; count2 = len(set2)

# Only want first three.

need = 3
while need > 0:
    # Continue until we find next intersect or end of a list.

    while idx1 < count1 and idx2 < count2 and set1[idx1] != set2[idx2]:
        # Advance pointer of list with lowest value.

        if set1[idx1] < set2[idx2]:
            idx1 += 1
        else:
            idx2 += 1

    # Break if reached end of a list with no intersect.

    if idx1 >= count1 or idx2 >= count2:
        break

    # Otherwise print intersect and advance to next list candidate.

    print(set1[idx1]) ; need -= 1
    idx1 += 1 ; idx2 += 1
```

The output is, as expected:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28]
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42]
0
6
12
```

If you needed a list at the end rather than just printing out the intersect points, you would simply initialise an empty container before the loop and the append the value to it rather than printing it. This then becomes a little more like your proposed solution but with the advantage of not needing hash tables or sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Create two arrays, call them `arr1` and `arr2`, of size `array_size` and populate them with integer values in ascending order.  Create two indexes, call them `i` and `j`, that will be used to iterate over `arr1` and `arr2` respectively and initialize them to 0.  Compare the first two values of each array: if `arr1[0]` is less than `arr2[0]` then increment `i`, else if `arr1[0]` is greater than `arr2[0]` increment `j`, else the values intersect and we can return this value.  Once we have returned k intersecting values we can stop iterating.  In the worst case scenario this will be i + j, O(n) if no intersections occur between both sets of values and we will have to iterate to the end of each array.

Here is the solution in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Design an algorithm to find the k smallest integers in S1 ∩ S2 in O(n) time.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typeset -a arr1 arr2 arr_answer
typeset -i array_size=20 k=5

function populate_arrs {
    typeset -i counter=0

    while [[ ${counter} -lt ${array_size} ]]; do
        arr1[${counter}]=$((${counter} * 2))
        arr2[${counter}]=$((${counter} * 3))

        counter=${counter}+1
    done

    printf "%8s" "Set1: "; printf "%4d" ${arr1[*]}; printf "\n"
    printf "%8s" "Set2: "; printf "%4d" ${arr2[*]}; printf "\n\n"
}


function k_smallest_integers_main {
    populate_arrs

    typeset -i counter=0 i=0 j=0
    while [[ ${counter} -lt ${k} ]]; do
        if [[ ${arr1[${i}]} -eq ${arr2[${j}]} ]]; then
            arr_answer[${counter}]=${arr1[${i}]}
            counter=${counter}+1; i=${i}+1; j=${j}+1
        elif [[ ${arr1[${i}]} -lt ${arr2[${j}]} ]]; then
            i=${i}+1
        else
            j=${j}+1
        fi
    done

    printf "%8s" "Answer: "; printf "%4d" ${arr_answer[*]}; printf "\n"
}

k_smallest_integers_main
```

Output:

```
  Set1:    0   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38
  Set2:    0   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36  39  42  45  48  51  54  57

Answer:    0   6  12  18  24
```

Comment: Just one small nitpick, `O(i+j)` seems to show a fundamental misunderstanding of complexity analysis. It's just `O(n)`, worst case. It would be more accurate to just state that worst case is `i + j` "steps" rather than introducing big-O into the mix.

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks, corrected, isn't something like O(m+n) just O(n) though or am I missing something here?